# Access Denied when trying to read a local file from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am going through questions and I found the exact same problem I have but the question was never answered. The link to the question is:

[javascript how to read a local file Dcnied access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829082/javascript-how-to-read-a-local-file-dcnied-access)

Basically, I am logged in as Administrator and running Visual Studio as administrator and my local file is under the C:\users\Administrator directory and my code is the exact same code as link's post and I'm getting Access Denied. here is my code:

```
        function readTextFile(file) {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                    var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                    alert(allText);
                }
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }

    function kmlBtnClick () {
        readTextFile("file:///c:/users/Administrator/KML/Operations.kml")

    }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you seeing the same error in all browsers? In chrome do you get a cross-origin-request error? Does adding http://localhost to trusted sites help?

Comment: The native file system is only available under the experimental flag.

Comment: Yes I am seeing the same browser error. Now as far as the experimental flag I'm not sure what your talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the answer to this. [Local file access with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

you can just create an input for file and select it there.

```
<input type="file">
```